# Logs shipped with wrong timestamp and timekey ignored

Tags: amazon-s3, fluentd

I want to ship my Vault logs to s3. Based on this [issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3/issues/187) I did this:

```
## vault input
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/vault_audit.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/vault.audit_log.pos
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  tag s3.vault.audit
</source>

## s3 output
<match s3.*.*>
  @type s3

  s3_bucket vault
  path logs/

  <buffer time>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/s3
    timekey 30m
    timekey_wait 5m
    chunk_limit_size 256m
  </buffer>

  time_slice_format %Y/%m/%d/%H%M
</match>
```

What I'd expect is for my logs to be shipped to S3 every 30 minutes, and be formatted in directories as ie: `logs/2019/05/01/1030`

Instead my logs are shipped every 2-3ish minutes on average, and the output time format in S3 is starting from the epoch ie: `logs/1970/01/01/0030_0.gz`

(the time is correctly set on my system)

Comment: You need to pass `time` to buffer section. `<buffer time>`. Can you try this and let me know if it fixed it?.

Comment: @Imran thanks for the help. adding `time` didn't help unfortunately, I added `<buffer time>` and restarted the agent. I've updated the question to reflect the config you suggested

Comment: @Imran FluentD also appears to be striping the `time` key from my JSON logs. Could that be related to the problem? ie: `{"time": "2019-05-07T17:50:13.301850515Z", "data": {}}` gets logged to S3 as `{"data": {}}` which is really unexpected.

Comment: try adding `include_time_key true` within match(after `path logs/`) and see if it works.

Comment: if your logs are not at all getting to S3, check whether your `match` pattern is working and permissions are in place for agent user to tail the files. Also, check my sample working configuration.

Comment: I have had this issue occur on a many number of occasions. It turned out that in addition to the time_format needing to be explicit (even though the default claims to be ISO compliant), sometimes logs will trickle in from sources whose clocks are wrong and all it takes is a single message whose timekey gets parsed in the past to cause the buffer to roll for that one and only log line(s). Meanwhile, your main buffer for the current time key is open. All those small files that get created? If you examine them as soon as they flush you'll find their time is either in the future or the past.

Comment: To follow up the issue you're describing is likely this one: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3/issues/348
I'm not sure what the easy fix is since fluentd uses a very arbitrary timeslice computation for determining the keyslice of the output file... other than making sure all your incoming logs are timed to the exact second with no lag. I've found myself being more content with a 12h timekey so that this happens much less frequently when logs slip in that are slightly delayed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample configuration which worked fine for me.

You need to make sure, you pass `time` to buffer section and also try to provide what kind of `format` it should be explicitly.

Check whether your match expression is working fine by checking agent start up logs. Also, try with `<match s3.**>`

```
<match>
  @type s3

  s3_bucket somebucket
  s3_region "us-east-1"
  path "logs/%Y/%m/%d/%H"
  s3_object_key_format "%{path}/%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}"
  include_time_key true
  time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L"

  <buffer tag,time>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/buffer/s3
    timekey_wait 5m
    timekey 30m
    chunk_limit_size 64m
    flush_at_shutdown true
    total_limit_size 256m
    overflow_action block
  </buffer>
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M%S
</match>
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave you the answer because the configuration works. My issues comes from the timestamp I believe, which I'm unable to parse: `2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621898Z`. Do you have any ideas of the accurate format string for this? I tried `time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"`

Comment: @Juicy I see you have created another question for this and replied there with some more info.