# Parsing time key with nanoseconds

Tags: fluentd

I have the following time key: `"2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621898Z"`

I can't figure out the `time_format` to parse this. I tried: `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"` which should work from my understanding. When I parse with it my logs are stored starting from the epoch, suggesting parsing is failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the configuration provided in your [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56025747/5030709) question then within `source` and `parse` section, specify `time_format` pattern which should take care of creating files based on your input file time

Here is example `source` configuration.

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  tag dummy
  dummy [
    {"message": "blah","time":"2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621898Z"}
  ]
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"
  </parse>
</source>

<match dummy>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

If your input time is under different JSON key name then additonally provide the `time_key`.

> {"message": "blah","mytimekey":"2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621898Z"}

`time_key mytimekey`

https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parse-section#parse-parameters